# Difference between ax.set_xlabel() and ax.xaxis.set_label() in MatplotLib 3.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, mplot3d

(This may be a naive question. Pardon me if so.)

I am using Python 3.7.1 and MatplotLib 3.0.1.

In below simple code, I used different ways to assign labels to axes. They *seem* to be equivalent from an OO perspective. But only the `x axis` label shows. Why?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(-2,2,60)
y = np.linspace(-2,2,60)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

z = xx**2 + yy**3

surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, cmap="viridis")

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')      # <====== This works
ax.yaxis.set_label('y axis') # <====== This doesn't work
ax.zaxis.set_label('z axis') # <====== This doesn't work
```

In below image, you can see only the label `x axis` is shown.

[image]

### ADD 1

According to [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_label.html), it seems the `matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_label()` approach should work.

In my case, the `ax.xaxis` is of type `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d.XAxis`. It's a little different type. But I think it *should* work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things called "labels" in matplotlib. There are e.g. axis labels, set via `set_xlabel`, there are tick labels, set via `set_ticklabels`, and there are artist labels, set via `set_label`.

Every artist in matplotlib has a label attribute. You usually encounter it when setting a label for it to be shown in the legend,

```
plt.plot(..., label="my label")
```

but it may be helpful for other cases as well. The above is equivalent to

```
line, = plt.plot(...)
line.set_label("mylabel")
```

So not only the `Line2D` object created by `plot` has a label, but equally the `matplotlib.axis.XAxis` has a label. This is the one you set with `ax.yaxis.set_label`. However, this is not by default taken into account when producing a legend, so its usefulness is questionable for the end user.

For the labels of the axes, `set_ylabel` is really the method to use for setting the ylabel. Internally, this would call `yaxis.set_label_text`, so as correctly pointed out by @DavidG, you can replace `ax.set_ylabel(..)` by `ax.yaxis.set_label_text(..)` (except for an additional argument `labelpad` that is taken by `set_ylabel`, but not by `set_label_text`.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the documentation you have shown for [`matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_label()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_label.html) it appears this is to do with assigning a label to the axis itself for potential use in a legend (see @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer for more explanation)

In any case, the equivalent to `ax.set_xlabel` is [`matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_text.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_text)

Therefore changing the code to:

```
ax.set_xlabel('x axis')     
ax.yaxis.set_label_text('y axis')
ax.zaxis.set_label_text('z axis')
```

Gives the desired output:

[image]